# SyntaxError: Unexpected token '*' error when i try to load my javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, django, import, three.js

i am getting this error SyntaxError: Unexpected token '*'. import call expects exactly one argument. when i load my javascript file in my django project.

this is my code btw

```
import * as THREE from 'three';

 const scene = new THREE.Scene();
 const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75,window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight,0.1,1000);
 const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    canvas: document.querySelector("#bg"),

 });
 renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
 renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth,window.innerHeight);
 camera.position.setZ(30);
 renderer.render(scene,camera);

 const geometry = new THREE.OctahedronGeometry(1,0);
 const color = new THREE.Color(134, 0, 255);
 const mat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: color,wireframe: true});
 const torus = new THREE.Mesh(geometry,mat);

 scene.add(torus);
 function animate(){
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    renderer.render(scene,camera);
 }
 animate()
```

i have already tried: looking if i have the correct javascript version that supports import i have and looking if i load the file correctly and triple checking if i have installed three correctly aswell. but for some reason it just does not work.

Comment: Try changing the import to `import * as THREE from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.117.1/build/three.module.js';` as stated somewhere at https://discourse.threejs.org/t/why-my-import-as-three-from-three-didnt-work/16048/7

Comment: i still got the same error.:( edit: oh i fixed it i had to add type="module" aswell thanks for the link that helped me to realise.